# Deserialization exception: Unable to find assembly while executing managed assembly from native application

Tags: c#, c++, exception, proxy

I'm writing a managed Direct3D 11 application using SlimDX. I need to create a proxy so that I can use PIX to debug my application( if I do not use a proxy I get an error in PIX: Failed to create process ).

Here is native app:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mscoree.h>
#include <metahost.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "mscoree.lib")

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    const std::wstring clrVersion = L"v4.0.30319";
    const std::wstring proxyDllPath = L"PIXProxyDLL.dll";

    ICLRMetaHost *pMetaHost = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost, (LPVOID*)&pMetaHost);
    if( FAILED(hr) )
        return -1;

    ICLRRuntimeInfo* runtimeInfo = 0;
    hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime( clrVersion.c_str(), IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo, (LPVOID*)&runtimeInfo );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
        return -1;

    ICLRRuntimeHost* host = 0;
    hr = runtimeInfo->GetInterface( CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (LPVOID*)&host );

    if( FAILED(hr) )
        return -1;

    hr = host->Start();
    if( FAILED(hr) )
        return -1;

    std::string arg( argv[1] );
    std::wstring app( arg.begin(), arg.end() );

    DWORD ret;
    hr = host->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain( proxyDllPath.c_str(), L"PIXProxyDLL.Proxy", L"Start", app.c_str(), &ret );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
        return -1;

    return ret;
}
```

Here is PIXProxyDLL(managed):

```
using System;

namespace PIXProxyDLL
{
    public class Proxy
    {
        public static int Start(string path)
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is call to execute native app in cmd.exe:

```
c:/MyNativeApp.exe "myManagedApp.exe"
```

I get an exception in my managed direct3d11 application:

```
Unable to find assembly 'SceneGenerator11, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at SceneGenerator.ProjectManager.DecodeBattery(String filename, GDEBattery& btry) in c:\Users\Paul\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SceneGenerator11\SceneGenerator11\ProjectManager.cs:line 4313
   at SceneGenerator.ProjectManager.OnDecodeBattery(_Manage mp) in c:\Users\Paul\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SceneGenerator11\SceneGenerator11\ProjectManager.cs:line 2783
```

How do I resolve this issue? As I understand it I need a SerializationBinder but I am not familiar with this feature.